# autoref: Short and long label

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I understand that it's possible to have \autoref generate references like Theorem 12, or Thm. 12, etc. where the label is always the same. Is there any way to have a short and long version of autoref? Sometimes I'll be referencing a theorem in equations, and I don't want Proposition 12 or something, but an abbreviation. In the main text, I will always want the long form. Is there a pain-free way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `\autoref`, I suggest you also load the `cleveref` package and then assign the abbreviated labels to `\cref` (via a `\crefname` directive) and the non-abbreviated labels to `\Cref` (via a `\Crefname` directive).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % make look of \cref emulate that of \autoref
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\crefname{prop}{Prop.}{Props.}             % abbreviated labels
\Crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions} % non-abbreviated labels

\begin{document}
\begin{prop} \label{prop:hello}
Hello.
\end{prop}
\cref{prop:hello}, \Cref{prop:hello}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following example defines a macro `\shortautoref`, which redefines the names for `\autoref`. As example, a section reference is used. Just extend the list of redefinitions to your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\shortautoref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\sectionautorefname{sec.}%
    \autoref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \section{First section}
  \label{sec:first}
  Autoref: \autoref{sec:first}\\
  Short autoref: \shortautoref{sec:first}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]